# How to pass an array of pointer by JNA?

Tags: jna

Java:

```
Pointer[] myArray;
```

myArrayis an array of Pointers.

C++

```
myfun(void** myArray){
    void *a = myArray[0];
}
```

How to pass an array of pointer by JNA?
I've tried `myfun(Pointer[] myArray)` in Java but it reported not support argument type in runtime like below:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class [Lcom.sun.jna.Pointer; is not a supported argument type (in method myfun in class com.xx.yy.zz)

Comment: Include your complete JNA mapping.  `Pointer[]` _is_ supported, but not necessarily in the context you actually used it.

Comment: thanks a lot , it seems void** in C++ can be converted to Pointer[] in Java, but Pointer[] in Java can not be converted to void** in C++

Answer (score 0):

thanks , I've solved this problem
create a structure
in Java:

```
public class xxPointer extends Structure {
    public Pointer myPointer;
```

in C++:

```
struct xxPointer {
    void* myPointer;
};
```

interface:
in Java:

```
myFun(xxPointer.ByReference br);
```

in C++:

```
myFun(xxPointer * xp)
```

in Java:

```
xxPointer.ByReference rp = new xxPointer.ByReference();
xxPointer.ByReference pointers = (xxPointer[]) rRecord.toArray(array count);
assignment value for pointers[i].myPointer
myFun(rp);
```